# Publishing a azure function from Visual Studio to Azure does not generate out bindings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions and trying to create a sample function to send/insert a message into Queue & Table storage.

I am using Visual Studio 20117 15.3.5 Professional edition (currently I am on trail version)

I am able to create a function and working fine in local, the issue is when I publish the function from Visual Studio to Azure its not copying/function.json is missing out bindings

see bellow screen shots

Visual Studio Code:
[image: Visual Studio Code]

After Publish to Azure, Function.json file:
[image: After Publish to Azure Function.json file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When publishing from VS, The output bindings are captured in the compiled binary (based on the attributes you see in your code), and have no need to exist in function.json. Only the triggers show up there, as they are needed to make the triggering infrastructure work.

Generally, you should ignore this file when dealing with VS deployments. Things will work correctly and you should view this file as an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm a little concerned that there are two different ways to read the output bindings (`function.json` and attributes from compiled functions). Seems like standardizing on `function.json` keeps everything consistent. Is there a benefit in reading the output bindings from the attributes in the compiled functions that you wouldn't get from `functions.json`?

Comment: It's the same as having source code in your .cs files vs. having it end up in a compiled binary. When working with VS, the only thing you need to be concerned about is your source code, including the attributes on your functions. Building your source code produces build artifacts (assemblies, function.json, and other things), and generally you should not be too concerned with the details of what you see there.

Comment: Thanks @DavidEbbo for the clarification. I have one more question, what is the or how to publish local.settrings.json part of publish process?

Comment: It's not meant to be deployed. It's best to use Azure App settings instead